# Вывод текста из базы данных mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, echo

Я пытаюсь вывести из базы данных текст, который там есть, но почему то выводится пустая переменная.

```
<ul>
            <li>See here:</li>
            <?php
                $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "test");

                if($link === false){
                    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
                }

                $result = mysqli_query("SELECT 'tex' FROM 'example' WHERE id = '1'");
                echo "<li> $result </li>";

                mysqli_close($link);
            ?>
        </ul>
```

Ошибок в консоли никаких нет. Страница тоже появляется.

[image: База данных сама]
Железнодорожная станция

Comment: не помешало бы еще mysqli_fetch выполнить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в самом запросе.

- имя поля и таблицы пишутся без кавычек
- необходимо выполнить `mysqli_fetch_array` - выбирает одну строку из результирующего набора и помещает в массив

Попробуйте отправить запрос вот так:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT tex FROM example WHERE id = '1'");
$deskRow = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$result = $deskRow['tex'];
echo $result;
```